# Swift. For loop iteration.

Tags: swift

Using the following:

```
func isosceles(triangleSides: Int)
{
    var y = 0

    for _ in 1...triangleSides {
        y = y + 1

        var stringBuilder = String()

        for _ in 1...y
        {
            stringBuilder += "*"
        }            
        println(stringBuilder)          
    }


}

isosceles(3)
```

I can make the following pattern:

```
*
**
***
```

I'm trying to write a function that outputs a sideways triangle of height 2n-1 and width n, so the output for n = 4 would be:

```
*
**
***
**
*

func triangle(triangleSides: Int)
{
    var y = 0
    var x = 0
    var index: Int

    for _ in 1...triangleSides {
        y = y + 1

        var stringBuilder = String()

        for _ in 1...y
        {
            stringBuilder += "*"
        }

        println(stringBuilder + "\n")

    }

    for _ in 1..<triangleSides{
        x = triangleSides - 1


        var index: Int
        var stringBuilder = String()

        for index in stride(from: triangleSides - 1, through: 1, by: -1) {
            stringBuilder += "*"
        }


        println(stringBuilder + "\n")


    }
}
```

I get

```
*
**
***
**
**
```

Obviously it's going to be me thats the problem with the way I am trying to do this. If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: learn how do use debugger and breakpoints to debug your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are quite a few things you're doing that you don't really need to do... but, your main problem is that your 3rd and 4th `for` loops are wrong.

The way it is now, it's looping from `1` to `triangleSides - 1` in the outer loop and `triangleSize - 1` to `1` in the inner loop. Since you're not using the actual index of the `for` loop, that just makes both the outer and inner loops run `triangleSides - 1` times.

What you want to do is loop from `triangleSize - 1` to `1` in your outer loop and `1` to the current value of your outer loop in your inner loop. It'll make it easier if you let the `for` loop do its job and assign `x` directly instead of ignoring the loop's index with `_` and manually calculating `x`.

Those changes would look like this (just the second set of `for` loops):

```
for x in stride(from: triangleSides - 1, through: 1, by: -1) {
    var stringBuilder = String()

    for _ in 1...x {
        stringBuilder += "*"
    }

    println(stringBuilder + "\n")
}
```

If you want to clean it up a little more, you can also let the `for` loop do its job in the first set of loops and get rid of the declarations of `x`, `y`, and `index` at the start of your function:

```
func triangle(triangleSides: Int)
{
    for y in 1...triangleSides {
        var stringBuilder = String()

        for _ in 1...y
        {
            stringBuilder += "*"
        }

        println(stringBuilder + "\n")

    }

    for x in stride(from: triangleSides - 1, through: 1, by: -1) {
        var stringBuilder = String()

        for _ in 1...x {
            stringBuilder += "*"
        }

        println(stringBuilder + "\n")
    }
}
```

Now, this:

```
triangle(3)
```

Outputs:

```
* 
**
***
**
*
```

Comment: Excellent thank you so much for you help. And the explaining things a bit further. I was working through some old C simple I/O examples and made things more confusing for myself than needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
func triangle(triangleSides: Int)
{
    var y = 0
    var x = 0
    var index: Int
    var stringBuilder = ""

    for _ in 1...triangleSides {
        stringBuilder += "*"
        println(stringBuilder)
    }

    for z in reverse(1..<triangleSides) {
        let index = advance(stringBuilder.endIndex, -1)
        stringBuilder = stringBuilder.substringToIndex(index)
        println(stringBuilder)
    }
}

triangle(4)
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

Comments.  I think the double loop was too complex.